# Is it possible to add a view between UISearchBar and navigation item in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Is it possible to add a view between UISearchbar and navigation item in storyboard ? If I add a view and then the UISearchbar, the UISearchbar becomes the child of view. The only problem is after a tableview search, the contents of the view is hidden.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in iOS 7:

1. On the storyboard, add a `UISearchDisplayController` to your view
   controller
2. In `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       // Set the displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar property
       self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;

       // Sample custom view for demonstration purposes
       UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
       customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

       // Create a UIBarButtonItem with your custom view      
       UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];

       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
   }
   ```

Which yields this (red square is the custom view):
[image: SearchBar in navigation item]

Comment: I need a view above Searchbar and below navigation item, so that company logo is seen at all times. Additionally, the solution should work both in portrait and landscape mode